# How identify the a web element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, jsoup

There is a website https://www.directenergy.com/ny , I need to select Natural Gas from Drop down and enter "19082" in the Zip Code Text box and clicking on the submit button, I get a new form (URL remains the same). I need to know how would I identify the web elements in this new form. I am now stuck with the new page contents. Please help me.

Thanks,
Naveen.

Comment: Have a look at http://selectorgadget.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath,
to find the xpath you can use this guide:

https://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/

It should look somthing like this:

```
  webDriver.findElement(
      By.xpath(
        "//*[@id="homeGetEnergy"]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input[1]"
      )
    ).sendKeys("19082");

  webDriver.findElement(
      By.xpath(
        "//*[@id="homeGetEnergy"]/div/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/button/span/b/em"
      )
    ).click();
```

Comment: Hi, I am done with these. After clicking submit in this form, you'll get a new form where there is a dropdown without id or name. I even tried it using xpath, it is not working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
driver.get("https://www.directenergy.com/ny");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='goto_service_type']"))).selectByVisibleText("Natural Gas");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='zipcode']")).sendKeys("19082");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span/b/em")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);

if(driver.getTitle().equals("Sign Up For Natural Gas In Pennsylvania | Direct Energy"))
{
    System.out.println("Inside another page..");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Redirection error.");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am done with these. After clicking submit in this form, you'll get a new form where there is a dropdown without id or name. I even tried it using xpath, it is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: I have tried this code on my end, it is working fine for me. Do you get any error while execute above code? if you get please pass error.

Comment: If this answer is `helpful` to you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`.